# Temp Sensor not working on ESP32

Tags: i2c, esp32, temperature-sensor

I am using SHT21 temp sensor with ESP32 using I2C. The sensor only reports temp of -273 and 0 for RH. The sensor is not faulty as I have tried this on an Arduino UNO with the same sketch and it works fine. I am using the default data and clk pins on ESP 32. Also I tried it on a different ESP32 board as well as powering the sensor from the ESP32 and externally but still get incorrect readings. I suspect it is more of a software issue than a hardware one. Could you please help me find the cause?

Here is my sketch:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Sodaq_SHT2x.h>


void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Humidity(%RH): ");
  Serial.print(SHT2x.GetHumidity());
  Serial.print("     Temperature(C): ");
  Serial.println(SHT2x.GetTemperature());
  Serial.print("     Dewpoint(C): ");
  Serial.println(SHT2x.GetDewPoint());
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: The two things that are different between your working- and non-working trials are the hardware (board and connections to the sensor) and the library code. Your own code and the sensor are already proven. So what is different between the Uno connections and ESP connections to your sensor? Between the Uno-specific and the ESP-specific code sections in the library (if any)?

Comment: In my code there is no UNO or ESP specific code. I use the exact same sketch on both microcontrollers. May be when it compiles there are certain things which change but I don't know about that. Other differences that I can think of are the I2C pins which are of course different for UNO and ESP32. I wonder if the library I am using can detect the correct data and clock pins on different mcu's.  But I am able to find the sensor when using the I2C address scanner. It just gives the wrong readings.

Comment: Maybe there is some MCU-specific code in the Sodaq_SHT2x library, such that maybe one section might compile for an Uno while another might compile for an ESP. That and connectivity, voltages, etc. seem to be the only differences. I agree that your own code should run on either MCU.

Comment: This is my first experience with ESP32 and so far using sensors on I2C bus is giving me a lot of issues. Good sensors (tested on arduino UNO) just stop working on ESP32. What am I missing here? Do I need to modify libraries and my code to make it ESP specific?

Comment: "so far using sensors on I2C bus is giving me a lot of issues" sounds like a clue, doesn't it? Especially if other sensors have given you the same problem. If that's the case, your issues sound very likely related to differences in hardware compatibility such as voltages, supply capability, connections, choice of ESP pins - something that is different about the ESP that applies consistently across the various sensors, and less likely to be software related. Has *any* sensor worked with ESP32 and I2C?

Comment: Exactly how is your sensor wired to the ESP32? What pins are connected to what pins? How is it powered? What happens when you run an I2C scanner on the ESP32?

Comment: @JRobert I doubt it's due to issues like voltage, supply capabilities etc. Both ESP32 and sensors am I having problem with are 3.3V and I have tried both powering the sensors using ESP32 and through external power supply. Another sensor that wasn't working initially on ESP32 was a BME280. But after sometime it started working. Same code, same circuit. Another sensor that worked right out of the box was an AHT10. So the I2C behaviour is pretty inconsistent.

Comment: @romkey It's a very basic setup. I am using 3.3V breakout board with 4 pins(Vin, GND, SCL, SDA). I am using the default I2C pins (D22 for SCL and D21 for SDA). Both the MCU and the breakout board are powered using external 3.3V supply.  The I2C scanner detects the sensor with it's address so ESP32 has no problem seeing the sensor

Comment: @Zaffresky that sounds solid - you wouldn't believe the number of people who wire stuff up and don't hook up GND or something like that... :) the only other issue there I can think of is if the wires are really long; that can cause issues with I2C. I'd try a different library that's known to work with the ESP32 - Adafruit and Sparkfun are both very good about this but unfortunately they don't seem to have an SHT21 library. FWIW, I've used BME280s with the ESP32 extensively with no problems.

Comment: There's a small chance that adding pull-up resistors to SCL and SDA might help - the ESP32's internal pull-ups are quite weak. A 47K resistor between SCL and 3.3V and SDA and 3.3V might make a difference.

Comment: @romkey you were right about the library. I have tried another library for SHT21 that was tested with ESP32 and it works like a charm :)  I was assuming that my tried & tested arduino libraries would work also for ESP32 but its not that simple. Anyways at least I know now where the issue lies

Comment: @Zaffresky in my experience many of them do but unfortunately not 100%. glad that resolved it!

Comment: The two main issues I encounter with sensors/I2C and different board types are that the needed pullups are different for 5V and 3.3V parts/systems, and if the library is written for AVR (i.e. Uno) it may not work properly on a ESP8266, etc, due to variances in the architecture, etc. So it's always good to try a few libraries, especially if you were able to detect the i2c device using the scanner sketch ;)

Comment: @PeterFeerick yeah I have learn't that now. I only had experience with AVR MCUs so far. I have learnt about the library issues now but you make a good point regarding the pull ups. Will keep that in mind as well